# Debugging a VM error in solidity

Tags: solidity, truffle, evm, truffle-test

I'm getting the following error while running a test in truffle:

> Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert

Now, the code is simply to big and complicated to run through Stackoverflow.  So my question instead is,

-How can I debug this? 
(more specifically: how can I get the VM logs and see exactly what is ducking up the test)

After a lot of trial and error I know exactly what function is misbehaving, I just don't know exactly what's misbehaving about it: here is the code in case it provides any clarity:

```
function onOCTReceived
(
 address operator, 
 address from, 
 uint256 amount, 
 bytes calldata data
) 
external 
returns
(
 bytes4
) 
{
    bobAndAlice(data);
    return (0x0);
}
```

important to note `bobAndAlice(data)` is working like a charm independently of the `onOCTReceived()` function so doubt the error is there, plus deleting it doesn't offer any more clarity on whats going on.

Edit: Additional testing shows that `onOCTReceived()` works perfectly fine in remix too.

Any pointers or help is very much appreciated.

Comment: It's likely that `bobAndAlice()` reverts in this _context_. The raw _data_ facilitates limitless possibilities. The function may have `require()` conditions that aren't met _in this context_. Consider posting that code so someone might pinpoint the issue.

Comment: When I run  `bobAndAlice` as a stand alone function with the same data input, it works as expected. The same error is returned when I delete `bobAndAlice` the exact same issue is returned, I suspect  the error might be on the return, but might be completely misguided here. :shrug:

Comment: "`bobAndAlice(data)` is working like a charm" with what `data`???

Comment: I don't think the data itself is relevant, the relevant part is that the `data` input is the same when executing as stand alone and when executing it within the function stated above, one works the other doesn't

Comment: Please check the edit and let me know how to debug the VM in truffle please, since I now think that the truffle VM is the actual issue:)

Answer (score 1):

When you call function `bobAndAlice` from the off-chain, the `msg.sender` that this function executes with is the address of the account which you have used for calling it.

When you call function `bobAndAlice` from the on-chain, the `msg.sender` that this function executes with is the address of the contract which you have used for calling it.

From your description, it sounds like this function performs some operation on `msg.sender`, which completes successfully when your account is used, but reverts when the contract is used.

It could be something as simple as `require(someCondition(msg.sender))`.

It could be something more complicated, for example, function `bobAndAlice` tries to send funds back to the caller (via `msg.sender.transfer`), but in the case of your contract, there is no fallback function to receive it, i.e., no implementation for `function() external payable`.

Without seeing the code of function `bobAndAlice`, it is rather impossible to tell...